# MVC Get Request that makes changes on the server

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC web app that I have started. Under normal circumstances when I am developing a site, and I require an edit page, I will have a GET request to get the record to edit, display it on screen, then a further POST request to save the changes to the database like so:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id) { // get the record and display }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(CustomClass model) { // save changes to the record}
```

Now I have the need to make changes to the record when you hit the edit GET request. The reason is that when you go into edit mode, I need to lock the record on the database so no-one else can go in on edit mode, or at least they will be warned. But this breaks the normal rules of a GET request never making server changes.

How would I accomplish this in the correct manner?

UPDATE

The reason this is needed isn't for concurrency issues saving to the database. The screen is used to allow customer contact. I can't have 2 users contacting a customer concurrently. I need to flag on this screen that someone else is currently in the record dealing with it. If someone is on the edit screen, that's what they will be doing. This is an internal application.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is not related to concurrency, at least not in the typical Computer Science definition.  Your concurrency is more of a human process concurrency (not contacting more than one customer).  Computer Science concurrency is concerned with the consistency of data when two users are working with the same record.

First of all, it's a very bad idea for queries (ie a get) to modify data.  Queries should be idempotent, although for obvious reasons that's not always possible (auditing is a good reason).  In general though, a get should not have side-effects.  This is particularly important since web browsers are free to "optimize" user experience by pre-loading pages it thinks the user might want to see.  But it only does this with get requests, not posts.

Another reason is for security considerations.  If you can modify data from a get, that means attackers can fool you into performing actions without your knowledge simply by placing an image on a page with the URL they want you to perform, often times making this a 1x1 sized pixel so you can't even see it.

Finally, there's the fact that web pages are stateless.  In other words, sure.. you can lock the page... but the web page only has access to the database for a moment.. what happens if the browser crashes, or the user just leaves the page open?  The record doesn't get "unlocked".  You can get around this by having a process to unlock zombie locks... or you could make your lock time-dependent (ie lock occurred at this time, it's valid for x minutes) but what happens if a user has the page open for longer than the lock time?

In general it's just not a good idea.  You should have very explicit lock semantics.  And in this case, what you really want is more of a mutex or even an access token... You have to request a token to be able to contact the user, and this token access can be a process unique in and of itself.  For instance, you may have a "Contact" table which stores contact attempts, and this table is used as part of the token acquiring process.

Comment: I am having a rethink about how I deal with locking, perhaps as part of the process, a POST request is first sent to lock, before redirecting to a get request for the edit page. Then this edit page will only show you the details if the lock is in place. This would get round the issue of modifying data on a get, and get round the issue of someone manually typing in the edit page when they shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend not to "lock" in the way you are describing, I would use a decoupled set of restful services. And upon edit of an existing resource use a PUT request. You could then in the header put details that it should succeed if the record is still fresh. If it has since changed you would receive an error.

There is a good article [here](http://blog.4psa.com/rest-best-practices-managing-concurrent-updates/) on this which I think you will find useful.
I've always had issues with locking mechanisms, as what happens when your client dies halfway through an edit and the database record is locked or if someone walks away half way through, you then get into timeout and lock recovery mechanisms, which I have since learned is a legacy issue you could do without.

Check out the article it may mean changing your code but I think for the better.

Upon seeing your comment:

If your business requirement is to immediately see if this is already under edit then the only way to really solve this is to place a record somewhere that says you are editing the record, this is a model I've come to regret later in several projects however the only sure fire way to ensure you operation is atomic really is to place a lock record but I'd not extend the record for the object in the database i'd have a separate lock table, complete with time-out mechanism from the get go if it really is a business requirement.

Comment: The problem I have is slightly different. It is a business requirement. And rather than finding out problems when you attempt to do the save, you need to know as soon as you go to edit mode. The reason being, that this screen is then used to contact customers. 2 users of the application cannot attempt to call the customer. So basically as soon as you go to this page, it needs to be locked. Not necessarily for concurrent updates, but for customer experience.

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement really is to "lock" the record then this would be a sensible approach.  Sure, making en edit in a GET isn't particularly RESTful, but the semantics of that argument can go either way.  You're not actually *editing* the resource itself, just locking it from *being edited*.  The resource remains unchanged.  It's a semantic difference between "data" and "meta data", but the whole question is about semantics anyway.

Be aware, however, that this kind of [pessimistic concurrency](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2010/07/16/optimistic-and-pessimistic-concurrency-a-simple-explanation.aspx) (locking records) tends to be a bit of a bad idea on web applications.  Is that *really* the requirement?  Or just somebody's interpretation of the actual business need?  You'll find it's very often the latter.

It's usually a more standard practice in web applications to perform an optimistic concurrency model.  Something as simple as a "last edited" time stamp on a record can be examined when editing the record.  If the record in the database has changed since it was fetched by this user, the user gets an error and is asked to make the changes again after fetching the updated version of the record.

It's mostly conjecture on my part, I don't know the actual business need or user experience here.  I'm just advising that pessimistic concurrency is an increasingly rare option in the industry.

Comment: I have updated the bottom of the question. It isn't for concurrency issues, it is a business requirement to stop 2 people dealing with the same record at the same time as customer contact will be initiated.

Comment: @eyeballpaul: In that case you'll likely want to avoid the semantics of "editing" and "locking" entirely, as they imply concurrency whereas that's not what's being done here. (It'll be confusing to later developers, including yourself once you've moved on to something else.) I would recommend that when viewing a record there is an available operation to "take" or in some way "claim" the record. This would be a POST which updates the state of the record. Then when other users view it (*not* "edit" it), they can see that state and the same operation is unavailable to them.

Comment: I have to agree with david on this, make absolutely sure that this business requirement cannot be dealt with in another way, if of course you have any say, I've seen this type of locking more in thick apps, and its still a bad idea generally :)

Comment: I am having a rethink about how I deal with locking, perhaps as part of the process, a POST request is first sent to lock, before redirecting to a get request for the edit page. Then this edit page will only show you the details if the lock is in place. This would get round the issue of modifying data on a get, and get round the issue of someone manually typing in the edit page when they shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a rethink about how I deal with locking, perhaps as part of the process, a POST request is first sent to lock, before redirecting to a get request for the edit page. Then this edit page will only show you the details if the lock is in place. This would get round the issue of modifying data on a get, and get round the issue of someone manually typing in the edit page URL when they shouldn't.

The business requirement of some sort of "locking" cannot change. And due to the contact applications being separate to the management application, I can't stop them contacting any customer if they get to this screen.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually locking the record of the customer table, you can have a separate special table which updates information like session details, table id and record id with timestamp in the GET method for the first user. If the second user accesses the same customer,  then in your GET method you first check this special table and if this customer record id is found, then you don't allow the second user to access the customer.

In the POST method, after updating the customer, remove the entries from the special table, thereby "freeing" the customer.

For handling browser crashes etc, you periodically check the special table and "free" the customer for invalid sessions.

Comment: This is more or less just the same. Whether you do it in the same table as the record, or a special record, you are breaking the norm for get requests not changing state server side and giving the same result on every request.